# Error de Copilot en visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, github

`GitHub Copilot` me ha empezado a dar problemas esta misma tarde...
el erro que me da es:

```
Your Copilot experience is not fully configured, complete your setup.
```

Siguiendo el enlace para configurarlo, solo me permite activarlo comprando una suscripción...

Esto es así? se ha vuelto de pago de la noche a la mañana o algo estoy haciendo mal?
Gracias.

Comment: De la noche a la mañana no... tiene una versión de prueba de 60 días (Por supuesto, si escoges la suscripción *anual* :) ). Era obvio que iba a acabar siendo de pago... las mejores herramientas suelen serlo y esta gente querrá ganar dineros :P

Comment: Todo claro entonces, muchas gracias.

Comment: _Mi amigo se llama billetín,..._

Comment: Me parece justo, solo estaba desconcertado y desinformado.